# sql for status using most recent date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've searched several other SO questions but I still can't seem to get the right result.  I would like to get all records from the `Document` table based on `CaseId` and having the most recent `Status`. I have two tables:

**Document:**

```
DocumentId   |   CaseId   |  Name
----------------------------------------
2            |     23     |  Document 1
3            |     23     |  Document 2
4            |     24     |  Document 3
```

**AuditLog:**

```
AuditLogId   |   Status  |  DocumentId |  Date Created
---------------------------------------------------------
10           |   Active  |      2      |    4/2/2017
11           |   Draft   |      2      |    4/1/2017
12           |  Released |      2      |    4/3/2017  
13           |   Draft   |      3      |    4/17/2017
14           |   Draft   |      4      |    4/17/2017
```

So the desired result for `CaseId: 23` would be:

```
Status    | DocumentId | CaseId | Name
----------------------------------------------
Released  |     2      |   23   | Document 1
Draft     |     3      |   23   | Document 2
```

I have got close with this query, however this only gives me the most recent of all results for `CaseId 23`, rather than grouping by `DocumentId`:

```
Select s.Status, lh.* from LegalHold lh join(
   Select Status, LegalHoldId 
     FROM LegalHoldAuditLog
     WHERE DateCreated = (select max(DateCreated) 
     from LegalHoldAuditLog)) s on lh.LegalHoldId = s.LegalHoldId
     WHERE lh.CaseId = 23
```

Comment: There is just one record for `DocumentId = 3` in the `AuditLog` table, and this record has `Status = Draft`. How come you have `Active` in the result?

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos Probably just got confused with the DocumentId field.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos Yes my mistake I have updated the result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using [**`cross apply()`**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx) to get the latest `Status` for each `DocumentId`.

```
select d.*, al.Status
from Document d
  cross apply (
    select top 1 i.Status
    from AuditLog i
    where i.DocumentId = d.DocumentId
    order by i.date_created desc
    ) as al
where d.CaseId = 23
```

[**`top with ties`**](http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/use-top-filter-with-ties-option) version using [**`row_number()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) :

```
select top 1 with ties d.*, al.Status
from Document d
  inner join AuditLog al
    on d.DocumentId = al.DocumentId
order by row_number() over (partition by al.DocumentId order by al.date_created desc)
```

Comment: `Top with ties` is a nice one!

Comment: @SqlZim Top with ties worked great however I did change ah to al in the parenthesis with `partition by` otherwise it did not work. Please let me know if that was not a mistake on your end.

Comment: @user2884789 Was a typo. Updated

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be at least one way to do it.

All you need is the value of Status from the latest row, according to the Date Created column in the AuditLog table.

```
SELECT (SELECT TOP 1 Status 
        FROM AuditLog 
        WHERE AuditLog.DocumentId = Document.DocumentId 
        ORDER BY [Date Created] DESC), 
        DocumentId, CaseId, Name
FROM Document
WHERE CaseId = 23
```

And shouldn't the value for Document 2 be "Draft"?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Common Table Expression` with `ROW_NUMBER` in order to prioritize records of `AuditLog` table. Then join to `Document` table to get expected result:

```
;WITH AuditLog_Rn AS (
   SELECT Status, DocumentId,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DocumentId 
                             ORDER BY [Date Created] DESC) AS rn
   FROM AuditLog
)
SELECT d.DocumentId, d.CaseId, d.Name, al.Status
FROM Document AS d
JOIN AuditLog_Rn AS al ON d.DocumentId = al.DocumentId AND al.rn = 1
```